# Is the prior in Bayes formula a probability or it can also represent a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, prior

Given the Bayes formula:

$$ p(\theta|D) = \dfrac{p(D|\theta)p(\theta)}{p(D)} $$

If there is a distribution (let's say $g$) over the parameter $\theta$, how should one rewrite the Bayes formula?

$D$ is the evidence and $\theta$ is the prior (model parameters).

Comment: Isn't $p(\theta)$ the distribution over the parameter $\theta$?

Comment: if $ \theta $ is fixed, then no. If $D$ is fixed then yes. Do you mean that $ \theta$ is a random variable @mhdadk?

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/532234/edit) your question and explain what $\theta$ and $D$ are?

Comment: So here, by saying that $g$ is a distribution over $ \theta $ I'm assuming that $\theta$ is a random variable. @mhdadk

Comment: You might want Bayes' Theorem for continuous random variables which is stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#For_continuous_random_variables

Comment: See this recent related question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/529961/7224

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bayes formula assumes that there is a distribution over every quantity, so there is no need to rewrite it.

Bayes formula applies to both discrete and continuous random quantities. If the quantities are discrete then the $p()$ are probability mass functions. If the quantities are continuous, then the $p()$ are probability density functions.

You refer to the possibility of "fixed" quantities in your comments, but there are no fixed quantites in Bayes formula. If $\theta$ was fixed (i.e., known) then the formula would be pointless. If $D$ was fixed, then it could not provide evidence about $\theta$. In Bayesian applications, $D$ is observed and $\theta$ is an unknown parameter that determines the distribution of $D$. In this context, $p(D|\theta)$ is the *likelihood function*, the probability (i.e., the likelihood) of observing that particular $D$ value as a function of $\theta$.